# JavaScript - Get CSS style of letter which is before caret (cursor) in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got contenteditable `div` with content:

```
<span style="font-weight: 700">S</span>
<span style="font-weight: 100">o</span>
<span style="color: red">m</span>
<span style="text-decoration: underline">e</span>
<span style="background-color: green">T</span>
<span style="text-decoration: line-through">e</span>
<span style="font-style: italic">x</span>
<span style="font-family: Arial">t</span>
```

And I want to get style of element which is before caret (cursor). For example if i have got caret between `Some` and `Text` I want to get `text-decoration: underline`. My code is below (working, but I gets style of last element (`font-family: Arial`)). How can I fix it, using JavaScript or/and JQuery?
Thanks for help.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var style = $('#Box span').last().attr('style');
  $('#Result').text('Result: ' + style);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Box" contenteditable="true">
  <span style="font-weight: 700">S</span><span style="font-weight: 100">o</span><span style="color: red">m</span><span style="text-decoration: underline">e</span><span style="background-color: green">T</span><span style="text-decoration: line-through">e</span><span style="font-style: italic">x</span><span style="font-family: Arial">t</span>
</div>

<button>Get result</button>
<p id="Result"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see below code. This can output the style declared on the element next to the cursor.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var selection = null;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    selection = document.selection;
  }
  
  if(selection && selection.anchorNode && selection.anchorNode.parentNode) {
    var style = selection.anchorNode.parentNode.style.cssText;
    $('#Result').text('Result: ' + style);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Box" contenteditable="true"><span style="font-weight: 700">S</span><span style="font-weight: 100">o</span><span style="color: red">m</span><span style="text-decoration: underline">e</span><span style="background-color: green">T</span><span style="text-decoration: line-through">e</span><span style="font-style: italic">x</span><span style="font-family: Arial">t</span></div>

<button>Get result</button>
<p id="Result"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found answer.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  document.execCommand('insertHTML', null, '<span id="test"></span>');
  $('#Result').text($('#test').parent().attr('style'));
  $('#test').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Box" contenteditable="true">
  <span style="font-weight: 700">S</span><span style="font-weight: 100">o</span><span style="color: red">m</span><span style="text-decoration: underline">e</span><span style="background-color: green">T</span><span style="text-decoration: line-through">e</span>
  <span
    style="font-style: italic">x</span><span style="font-family: Arial">t</span>
</div>

<button>Get result</button>
<p id="Result"></p>
```

Comment: Good try Good result

Answer (score 1):

In first, you need to keep last element, that was under mouse pointer. Then, you could get any property or attribute of it, when mouse is clicked.

```js
let element;
$(".container").on("mouseover", "span", function(e) {
  element = $(e.target);
});
$(".container").on("mousedown", function(e) {
  $("#out").html(element.attr("style"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span style="font-weight: 700">S</span>
  <span style="font-weight: 100">o</span>
  <span style="color: red">m</span>
  <span style="text-decoration: underline">e</span>
  <span style="background-color: green">T</span>
  <span style="text-decoration: line-through">e</span>
  <span style="font-style: italic">x</span>
  <span style="font-family: Arial">t</span>
</div>
<div id="out"></div>
```

I'm not sure, what the snippet is exactly solution of your problem, but I hope, it helps you to get started.
**Note**, if you move mouse from right to left, then when you click between two `<span>`s the right element's style will be displayed. But it is question about couple of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call like
    $("#Box span:nth-child(4)").attr ("style");

Answer (score 0):

Your content editable div is a sequence of span elements. Hence, the caret positionn can be cosidered like the index of the span inside the div itself.

Therefore, my proposal is based on getting the caret position on **mouseup** and saving this value as a data attribute of the content editable div.

```js
//
// get the caret pos
//
$('#Box span, #Box').on('mouseup', function(e) {
    var pos = 0;
    if (this.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'div') {
        pos = $('#Box span:last').index();
    } else {
        e.stopPropagation();
        pos  = $(this).index();
    }
    $('#Box').data('caretPos', pos);
});

$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    var caretPos = $('#Box').data('caretPos');
    var style = $('#Box span').eq(caretPos).attr('style');
    $('#Result').text('Result: ' + style);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="Box" contenteditable="true">
    <span style="font-weight: 700">S</span><span style="font-weight: 100">o</span><span style="color: red">m</span><span style="text-decoration: underline">e</span><span style="background-color: green">T</span><span style="text-decoration: line-through">e</span><span style="font-style: italic">x</span><span style="font-family: Arial">t</span>
</div>

<button>Get result</button>
<p id="Result"></p>
```